# Contraction of 'Am I not'?

Tags: contractions, be

To the best of my understanding the correct contraction of "Am I not" is "aren't I". However, growing up in Scotland I very frequently heard an alternative contraction "amn't I". I think this though is extremely uncommon outside of Scotland.

Now obviously the latter uses the correct part of the verb for "I" and the former does not. I was wondering if anyone knew how we got the wrong part of the verb in the right contraction, and the right part of the verb in the wrong contraction?

Comment: Because *ain't I?* became vulgar and we needed an alternative.

Comment: Because amn't I joins /m/ and /n/ sounds and is difficult to speak, which defeats the purpose of contraction.

Comment: According to this website, *aren't I* is also incorrect. *Am I not* is normally not contracted. http://www.grammarerrors.com/grammar/arent-iam-i-not/

Comment: _Aren't I_ is common, but _ain't I_ is probly more common, though far less recorded.

Comment: @John Lawler Most English speakers are allegedly Indian (although I'm really making the point that _ain't I_ sounds distinctly non-standard in the UK).

Comment: @TusharRaj: nevertheless, as the original poster states "amn't" is actually used by a significant minority of native English speakers, and I doubt they find it particularly difficult to say.

Comment: @sumelic What people find easy to say depends heavily on the native language they know. People who speak Semitic languages find the /ch/ sound easier than others, for instance (so _Chanukah_ becomes _Hanukah_).